# Get CultureInfo by culture English name

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to get `CultureInfo` by [culture English name](http://www.csharp-examples.net/culture-names/)?

Imagine we have got: Danish, English, Spanish and etc...

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
var names = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures).ToLookup(x => x.EnglishName);
names["English"].FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Works perfectly with `x.ThreeLetterWindowsLanguageName` and any other NLS columns. Thanks for the code!

Answer (score 9):

```
var EnglishCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                                .Where(r => r.EnglishName == "English");
```

Or if you need `FirstOrDefault`

```
var EnglishCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures)
                                .FirstOrDefault(r=> r.EnglishName == "English");
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no builtin method to get a culture by it's english name, so you could write one:

```
public static CultureInfo getCultureByEnglishName(String englishName)
{
    // create an array of CultureInfo to hold all the cultures found, 
    // these include the users local culture, and all the
    // cultures installed with the .Net Framework
    CultureInfo[] cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures & ~CultureTypes.NeutralCultures);
    // get culture by it's english name 
    var culture = cultures.FirstOrDefault(c => 
        c.EnglishName.Equals(englishName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    return culture;
}
```

Here's a **demo**: http://ideone.com/KX4U8l

Comment: Tim can the comparison be replaced with `c.EnglishName.Equals(englishName,StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)` ?